# Regex pattern match to extract time from a string in Javascript giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match possible ways to represent time. I am trying to match X, XX, XX:XX, X am, X pm, XXXX hr etc where X is a possible number which can represent time.

```
timereg = /([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]|[1-9])[:\s]*([0-5][0-9])?[\s]*(am|pm|hrs|hr)?/gi
```

I tried the following sample strings for a regex match and have the output that I see in chrome console below each trial.

```
match = timereg.exec("Pick up at 5pm")
["5pm", "5", undefined, "pm"]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up at 5:30")
["5:30", "5", "30", undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 5")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 15")
["15", "15", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 05")
["05", "05", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 20")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 21")
["21", "21", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 22")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 23")
["23", "23", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 1")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 2")
["2", "2", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 3")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 4")
["4", "4", undefined, undefined]

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 5")
null

match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 6")
["6", "6", undefined, undefined]
```

I see '21', '23', '2', '4', '6' match whereas '20', '22', '1', '3', '5' do not. Am unable to figure out why that is the case. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to use of global `g` flag in your regex and repeat use of same regex. 
Regex object remembers `lastIndex` when used with `g` flag between multiple `exec` or `test` method calls.

Remove `g` flag and this will be fixed.

Or else place this code to reset `lastIndex` property before calling `exec` every time:

```
timereg.lastIndex = 0;
match = timereg.exec("Pick up kids at 20");
```

Comment: the reason i had **g** flag is to match all occurrences of the search pattern. So for example "pick up at 5 pm and 7 pm" should match '5 pm'  as well as '7 pm'. Removing g only does the first match. How can I modify my regex to match all occurrences?

Comment: I got it. Executing the same regex again if using **g** till it returns null returns all the matches.